# access form elements in java script dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to get one of the form variables dynamically in my javascript function, which takes the parameters of form and element name to be accessed in that form.

Say, i will be calling on some button click like this `onClick="javascript:init(this.form, 'USERNAME')"`

If i do it as : `document.getElementById(formName).USERNAME.value.` This works. But, i dont have to give the element name directly. I want to read it from the passed arguments.

So, if i do it as below: `document.getElementById(formName).elem.value` - this gives an exception saying cannot get value of undefined

```
function init(form, elem){
            try{
                var formName = form.name;
                var elementValue = document.getElementById(formName).elem.value;
                ..
            }catch(e){
                alert(e.message);
            }                           
        }
```

Kindly suggest me. How can i get the passed elem value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should probably be `var elementValue = document.getElementById(formName)[elem].value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case in order to access properties of an object you can use the following notation:

```
something[elem].value
```

Consider the following code:

```
var prop = "a",
    obj = {a: 1};

obj.a === obj["a"] === obj[prop];
```

Then your code will look like:

```
function init(form, elem){
    try {
        var formName = form.name,
            elementValue = document.getElementById(formName)[elem].value;
            // ...
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a button to pass the value to the javascript. The button will get the value(ex: from textbox) and will pass it to the javascript.

So,

```
<input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" />
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="init(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Comment: Yes sughan90, your suggestion makes sense. I will follow the same. Thanks!